# Kotlin extension functions vs utils/helpers

Tags: kotlin, architecture

While searching on the internet for information I found it difficult to get a good understanding of which approach should be taken.

One concern is that Util or Helper class is considered an antipattern because it often violates Single Responsibility Principle.

Yet Util or Helper classes are still widely used.

Are there any good reasons to prefer one or another?

Comment: For me extension function is basically a static util, but one that is closely related to a specific object. I always prefer extensions if only it seems reasonable to choose one of its parameters as the "main" one. If parameters are rather "equal", I prefer to use a regular static function or sometimes create two extensions on both sides - if it makes sense.

Comment: @broot, thanks for reply. If extension requires class A and class B. Would you implement that extension on class A and class B as in A would have full implementation and B extension would call A extension?

Comment: Sometimes yes, not very often. For example, we have some kind of parent-child relation between objects and we define `addChild()` on one side and `addTo()` on another. Or we have string and regex objects. Usually in such cases only one side is extension and another is a regular function, but sometimes it makes sense to have both as extensions. Other than that, I have exactly the same experience as in accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is probably too opinion-based…

But in my experience, most of the utility/helper methods I used to write in Java were related to a particular class or interface: I had a load of String- and char-based methods, a load of methods that used a Collection or List or array, a load of methods for handling Components and Frames and other Swing classes, and so on.  I wasn't thinking of them as extension methods when I wrote them (mostly long ago!), but in hindsight that's how they seemed to go.

So when converting things to Kotlin, almost all of my utility methods fell out as top-level extension methods.  I didn't initially intend that, but it seemed the most natural way.

And I expect that will apply to the majority of helper and utility methods.  I'm sure there *are* cases where a utility class is more appropriate — but in my experience those cases are pretty rare.

You should also consider methods in companion objects; that's the most natural place for factory methods, and for other ‘static’ functionality that's closely related to a class without fitting into a normal instance method.